# Слетает верстка при масштабировании

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, масштабирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При масштабе в x1.1 все держится нормально, но если более:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что данная кнопка - простой фон на футере, каким образом делается оптимизация при изменении масштабирования я еще не представляю, буду рад советам и best practice.

Код:

```css
footer {
  height:72px;
}

.footer{
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 1120px;
  background: url(../images/вертолеты_футер_сплошной.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;

}

#btnText{
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:1020px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font: 13px 'Micra','Arial', serif;
  padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Песочница</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"
<body>


<footer>
  <div class = "footer">

    <div class = "listMenu" >

        <ul>
          <li>ПРОБКИ</li>
          <li>КАРТЫ</li>
        </ul>


    </div>


    <span id = "btnText">список предприятий<br> корпорации</span>

  </div>

</footer>

</body>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Зачем использовать zoom, если для тестирования верстки можно (нужно) использовать инструменты разработчика https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUBTQ.png

Comment: @Elena спасибо, покопаюсь, раньше не залезал туда, тем не менее от зума пользователя верстку это не спасет)

Comment: + viewport не задан и видимо фон или кнопка не адаптированы, кода маловато чтобы что-то понять

Comment: @Elena но это основной использующийся код, по сути весь футер состоит из одного списка, который в рамках вопроса - не нужен. И это весь код, что есть.
Футер с бэкграундом картинкой, на которую я накладываю текст( если присмотритесь - там left:1020px;) с position:absolute;
Чем viewPort может помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй fluid typography. Трюк основан на такой формуле

`12px + (24-12)*(100vw-240)/(1920-240)`

Суть в том, что размер шрифта рассчитывается в зависимости от размера экрана и пересчитывается при reflow, которое происходит при ресайзе страницы. В данном случае шрифт 12px будет на экране шириной 240px и при увеличении ширины экрана размер шрифта будет масштабироваться пропорционально до 24px при ширине экрана в 1920. Тебе надо определиться, какие у тебя ширины экрана, а потом подобрать соответствующие размеры шрифта, чтобы текст не вылезал за фон. Я бы так попробовал.

PS а если юзер будет тупо увеличивать масштаб шрифта в браузере, то это не твоя проблема, а его - значит ему так удобнее.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, только я не совсем понял о чем Вы, в терминологии еще разбираюсь, можно попроще?Что такое reflow и как это использовать в коде(в рамках имеющегося кода, если честно - не понимаю где это должно находиться)?

Comment: рассчитываешь шрифт прямо в стилях по формуле выше. Если правильно подберешь размеры шрифта и экранов, на которые ты рассчитываешь, это решит  проблему отображения на устройствах с экранами разных размеров. Пользовательское масштабирование - зажал ctrl и крутишь колесико мыши - это не проблема, не парься. А reflow - это то, что делает rendering engine браузера, когда ты ресайзишь окно, вставляешь новые тэги и т.д. После этого браузер пересчитывает стили и применяет их заново.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: и используй относительные единицы измерения (%, em), а не абсолютные (px).

Comment: а может быть такое, что использовав em он перестанет себя так вести?

Comment: у тебя изображение фоном. Текст-то будет по идее влезать в блок, но фон уже не будет точно соответствовать блоку. Я бы разбил всю конструкцию на прямоугольник с текстом (и фоном бы пустил паттерн) и на примыкающие треугольники слева и справа с помощью псевдоэлементов (с тем же паттерном в качестве фона). Целиком изображение класть не лучший вариант.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под словом "паттерн"?В голове синглтоны и фасады)

Comment: я имею в виду, что из твоего фонового изображения вырежи квадратик, например, 10х10 пикселей - такой будет серенький с  полосками наискосок - это я имею в виду. И используй в качестве фона для блоков.